# how to pass output of HTTP request Task to variable in Swift

Tags: swift, httprequest

In Chrome browser, I input this address

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

Then I see output on Chrome window:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

Now my question is that, can i do this in Swift?
Accessing an http address then get the output?
Now on this [webpage](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/http-get-request-example-in-swift/), i find the below code.

```
import SwiftUI

// Create URL
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")

guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

// Create URL Request
var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)

// Specify HTTP Method to use
request.httpMethod = "GET"
// Send HTTP Request
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    
    // Check if Error took place
    if let error = error {
        print("Error took place \(error)")
        return
    }
    
    // Read HTTP Response Status code
    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
    }
    
    // Convert HTTP Response Data to a simple String
    if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
    }
    
}
task.resume()
```

I run this code in Playground in XCode. As it says on the webpage I got the right output:

Response data string:
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "delectus aut autem",
"completed": false
}

But it prints on the console of XCode. I cannot find a way to pass this output to a variable. So I cannot go further.
I tried add lines like:

return dataString

all got error.
Or put it in a Func(), then call the function, also got error.
I am not a programmer and very new to Swift, hope people here can help.

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be answered on SO, because you seem to just not know how to start. Try to follow some tutorials on swift to get an idea of what you would have to do. Try to come up with a solution and come back with a specific qestion when you get in to trouble.

Comment: If you don´t want to learn, you are on the wrong website. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode from JSON and store the result in an object.

1. Create an object that conforms to `Codable` and can store the result - it need to have all the properties of the JSON:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
}
```

2. Create a function to decode:

```
    func decode(data: Data) -> MyObject? {
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: data)
            return result
        } catch {
            print("\n-->> Error decoding JSON: \(error), \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

3. Use the function:

```
if let data = data {

                // downloaded will store the result from the JSON
                let downloaded = decode(data: data)

                print(downloaded)   // Optional(Test_Swift.MyObject(userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false))
                print(downloaded?.title ?? "Could not decode")  // delectus aut autem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I run your code, got error: Cannot find 'json' in scope.

Comment: @CaiYu: Just use your data. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I run your new code, got error: Cannot find 'data' in scope

Comment: @CaiYu: you have place it after `// Convert HTTP Response Data to a simple String`.

Comment: Thanks for your time again. I tried. Then I add "print(downloaded)" after "task.resume()". it still have error: Cannot find 'downloaded' in scope. The output of the http-request still not going out of the {} of the task. Actually I dont need to parse the output string. I can use other way to extract what i want. I only want to use a variable to track this output String out of task {}.

Comment: @CaiYu: you should pass “downloaded” to an external class before ending the task, I assumed it was clear but I stand corrected.. Try following the recommendation on the comments: watch some tutorials on the basics of Swift and view models.

Comment: thank you, you are so patient. i did find what's wrong and begin new learning curve.